# Как заставить срабатывать min-height

Tags: css, css3

Добрый день уважаемые. Возник вопрос, как сделать что б при ресайзе страници с меню навигации, задний фон (родительский элемент) растягивается на выпадающие блоки? 
Приведу пример

```css
.header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  min-height: 86px;
  min-width: 100vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.headWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.block_logo {
  margin-top: 44px;
}

.block_logo__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 89px;
  color: #b6b4b3;
}

.block_navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 55px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
  background-color: #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.block_navigation__full {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

.block_navigation__item {
  margin-left: 62px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block_navigation__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.block_navigation__link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 3;
}

.block_navigation__link:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block_search {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.block_search__wrappen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_search__fild {
  width: 263px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(205, 205, 205, 0.38);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block_search__fild::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild::-moz-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild::placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 22px;
  background: transparent url("../../img/btn-search.svg") no-repeat;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <!-- Code -->
  <div class="headWrapper ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="block_logo">
            <h1 class="block_logo__title">Logo</h1></div>
          <div class="block_navigation">
            <ul class="block_navigation__full">
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="block_search">
              <div class="block_search__wrappen">
                <input class="block_search__fild" placeholder="search" type="search">
                <button class="block_search__button"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Я понимаю что это происходит потому что у меня у блока .block_search {float:right} задан. Если его убрать то всё будет тянуться правильно, и min-height у родителя будет правильно отрабатывать, но всё таки как реализовать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
.block_navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  min-height: 86px;
  min-width: 100vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.headWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.block_logo {
  margin-top: 44px;
}

.block_logo__title {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 89px;
  color: #b6b4b3;
}

.block_navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 55px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
  background-color: #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block_navigation__full {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

.block_navigation__item {
  margin-left: 62px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block_navigation__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.block_navigation__link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 3;
}

.block_navigation__link:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block_search {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.block_search__wrappen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_search__fild {
  width: 263px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(205, 205, 205, 0.38);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block_search__fild::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild::-moz-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild:-ms-input-placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__fild::placeholder {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 17px;
  opacity: 0.19;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.block_search__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 22px;
  background: transparent url("../../img/btn-search.svg") no-repeat;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <!-- Code -->
  <div class="headWrapper ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="block_logo">
            <h1 class="block_logo__title">Logo</h1></div>
          <div class="block_navigation">
            <ul class="block_navigation__full">
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="block_navigation__item"><a class="block_navigation__link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="block_search">
              <div class="block_search__wrappen">
                <input class="block_search__fild" placeholder="search" type="search">
                <button class="block_search__button"></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а из-за чего такая проблема происходит?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting